# How to don´t repeat values stored in database

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench

I´m creating a database `addrees` and I want to know what I need to set in `Mysql` to don´t store repeat values?

Like

Addrees 1 ("teste",1,new york,eua);

Addrees 2 ("teste",1,new york,eua);

If this happen my database will not store.

So what I need to do?

Comment: Add a unique key on the column that need to be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To alter an already existing table, run this MySQL command:

```
alter table yourtablename add unique index(firstcolumn, secondcolumn, thirdcolumn, fourthcolumn);
```

That'll add the unique constraint to the specified columns.  Here's how to specify such a constraint in the CREATE TABLE.

```
CREATE TABLE buyers ( 
 buyer_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
 first_name CHAR(19) NOT NULL, 
 last_name CHAR(19) NOT NULL, 
 age SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
 post_code SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
 UNIQUE idx_flname_age (first_name,last_name,age)
);
```

The primary key constraint will do this too, as mentioned by @Ajeesh

EDIT:
As per the suggestion in the comment, if you want to avoid errors generated by this unique constraint, you have three good options:

```
INSERT IGNORE
```

and

```
INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

and

```
REPLACE
```

INSERT IGNORE will not do anything if the insert violates the unique constraint, except log a harmless warning.  The table will be left as is, and no error would be reported.  This may be desireable in some cases.

More commonly is the second option, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, which says "Well, if the key already exists, then update that key's row like this instead."

And lastly is REPLACE, which will, if the key already exists, delete the row, then do an INSERT as normal.  If the key did not exist previously, it will simply act as an INSERT.

This stack overflow answer has some examples.

["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Comment: It would be great to mention special procedures required to avoid errors during insertion/updating this table. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to call these fields a UNIQUE_KEY

Answer (score 0):

To make a column to be **distinct** you need to have **Primary Key constraint/Unique Key**. Primary key is used for relating one table with another and it's values should **not be NULL**. But in your case you can have **Unique constraint** to store only unique/distinct values.